# How can we initialize an OpenGL in a section of a QML window?

Tags: opengl, qml

I am making a windows application in which I need to initialize a OpenGL instance in a section of a QML window on clicking a button.

Comment: show some code maybe?

Answer (score 2):

In Qt 5.5.0 there should be an example of what you are looking for. From the welcome screen in Qt Creator you should be able to switch to "Examples" tab, type "OpenGL" and find what you are looking for.

Here, as a part of Qt documentation, is explained how to render OpenGL scene in QML window:
[Scene Graph - OpenGL Under QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html)